# A cleaner way of "transforming" Cursors in Pojo(s)

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-cursoradapter

I do a lot of apps that use SQLite and very often cannot design the database, because I have to use the Schema defined by the customer.

Obviously :-P the UX/UI designer does not care about the underlying data...she/he has to be cool!

So I, not infrequently, have to use a lot of `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` with very big SQL queries (but thanks to the power of ContentProviders and Services this is not a big problem).

What bores me is the "cut/paste" (or static final) code for handling the different Cursor(s) from all the adapters `.getItem(position)`.

So I was thinking of a way to keep things more clean, something like this.

#### CursorHandler.java

Implementations of this interface will convert a Cursor into an object.
**`T`** is the target type the input Cursor will be converted to.

```
public interface CursorHandler<T> {
   T handle(Cursor cu)
}
```

#### CursorHandlerAdapter.java

Create a custom CursorAdapter that will use the above interface to automatically convert a cursor to a specified pojo

```
abstract
public class CursorHandlerAdapter<T> extends CursorAdapter {

   private LayoutInflater    mInflater  = null;
   private CursorHandler<T>  mHandler   = null;

   public CursorHandlerAdapter(Context context, CursorHandler<T> handler) {
     super(context, null, 0);
     mHandler  = handler;
     mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   }

   @Override
   public T getItem(int position) {
     Cursor cu = (Cursor)super.getItem(position);
     return ((cu == null) ? null : mHandler.handle(cu));
   }


   protected T getItem(Cursor cu) {
     return mHandler.handle(cu);
   }

   protected LayoutInflater getLayoutInflater() { return mInflater; }   
};
```

#### Usage example

Suppose we have a pojo, let's call it *Item*:

```
public class Item  implements Parcelable {

   public long     id;
   public String   code;
   public String   title;
   public String   description;
   public String   imageUrl;

   public Item() {  }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");
      sb.append("id=");
      sb.append(this.id);
      sb.append(", ");
      /* append the others fields */
      return sb.toString();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj == null) return false;
      if (obj == this) return true;
      if (!(obj instanceof Item)) return false;

      Item test = (Item)obj;

      boolean result = true;
      result = result && (this.code == test.code || 
         (this.code != null && this.code.equals(test.code)));
      return result;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      int result = 8;
      result = 31 * result + (this.code == null ? 0 : this.code.hashCode());
      return result;    
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
      parcel.writeLong(this.id);
      parcel.writeString(this.code);
      /* write the others fields */
   }

   static final
   public Creator<Item> CREATOR = new Creator<Item>() {
      @Override
      public Item createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
         return new Item(source);
      }

      @Override
      public Item[] newArray(int size) {
         return new Item[size];
      }
   };

   private Item(Parcel in) {
      this.id = in.readLong();
      this.code = in.readString();
      /* read the others fields */
   }
};
```

Let's create our CursorHandler implementation:

```
public class ItemCursorHandler implements CursorHandler<Item> {

   @Override
   public Item handle(Cursor cu) throws SQLException {
      Item item = new Item();

      int idx = cu.getColumnIndex(CommonsColumns.ID);
      if (idx != -1)
         item.id = cu.getLong(idx);

      idx = cu.getColumnIndex(ItemColumns.CODE);
      if (idx != -1)
         item.code = cu.getString(idx);

      idx = cu.getColumnIndex(ItemColumns.TITLE);
      if (idx != -1)
         item.title = cu.getString(idx);

      idx = cu.getColumnIndex(ItemColumns.DESCRIPTION);
      if (idx != -1)
         item.description = cu.getString(idx);

      idx = cu.getColumnIndex(ItemColumns.IMAGE_URL);
      if (idx != -1)
         item.imageUrl = cu.getString(idx);

      return item;
   }
}
```

and, then, the related CursorAdapter:

```
public class ItemsCursorAdapter extends CursorHandlerAdapter<Item> {

   public ItemsCursorAdapter(Context context) {
      super(context, new ItemCursorHandler());
   }

   @Override
   public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
     /* Here we can fetch our pojo */ 
     Item item = getItem(cursor);

     /* Get the ViewHolder as usual and fill/set the views */
     ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
     holder.xxxx.setYYY(....); 
   }

   @Override
   public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
      View rowView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.my_very_cool_layout, parent, false);

      ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.xxxx = (YYYY)rowView.findViewById(R.id.yyyy);
      ...
      ...
      rowView.setTag(holder);

      return rowView;
   }

   static
   private class ViewHolder {
      YYYY  xxxx;
      ...
      ...
   };
}
```

In ours Fragments or Activities we can retrieve the pojo:

```
ItemsCursorAdapter adapter = ...
Item value = adapter.getItem(position);
/* do whatever with the pojo */
```

In this way I don't need to "cut/copy or singletonize" all the different cursorToPojo methods.

Is this a proper way of handling the Cursor ? or there are some possible drawbacks ?

Could you point me to more consolidated alternatives ?

Best Regards,
LuS

Comment: if you have a Cursor why not to use a SimpleCursorAdapter ? or i miss something ?

Comment: @pskink you are right, maybe the question wasn't so clear (I'll change the title). What I'm asking is if there is a cleaner "pattern" to convert the Cursor obtained from [Simple]CursorAdapter.getItem(position) to a Pojo.

Comment: and why actually you need a POJO?

Comment: for instance suppose you have a big list with all products, then when the user tap on an item, I need to show the Product details in another fragment (or Activity)..in that case I need a Pojo to "parcelize" the infos..and avoid to requery on the specied item id.

Comment: well, you can easly pass the Uri that your ContentProvider can use, unless you dont use a ContentProvider ?

Comment: yes, I use always ContentProviders, so you are suggesting me that doing the query (invoking the ContentProvider with the item uri) is better then "parcelize" the Pojo. If so, I'm happy to hear that! I'll be glad to skip all the Pojo(s) maybe I was overthinking..thanks!

Comment: yes see the Notepad tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html, btw your concept was smart though

Comment: ok @pskink thanks for your time. Now I'll think about. Skipping the intermediate creation of Pojo(s) would spare much "copy/memory/allocation" operations. If you write an answer where you suggest me to not use Pojo(s) I'll give you a vote.

Comment: Well I would be somehow for POJOs, how about creating a custom loader that maps cursor to arraylist of pojos while loading on background thread? Btw in your source youre creating a new pojo every bindView call, thats a no-no

Comment: @VlastoBennyLava you are right! I definitively changed this. Now I'm using only cursors, passing the _id and then in the receiver (fragment, activity etc) I requery by _id (or if there are more data to handle, I use a custom loader as yoy say). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using a ContentProvider then dont pass POJOs, pass an Uri your ContentProvider can use

Comment: so you think passing a item uri to detail activity and hitting the database there again in the detail acitvity is faster than making a pojo from cursor row, parcelabling it and sending it to detail activity?

Comment: is it faster? it depends on data you are passing

Comment: Lets say a classic concept of Activity with a ListView, where onItemClick takes you to DetailActivity which displays items details

Comment: try to use a POJO that contains. a Bitmap 1000x1000 px, try to Parcelize it and you will see the result

Comment: Well in that case obviously, I meant more of a general use-case of POJO with primitive data types; I think this is more of a discussion about cursors vs pojos; btw I am not saying youre wrong, I am just asking